# .Net MemoryCache Not Working! Cache is getting invalidated and re-populated per Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, caching, memorycache

I am not sure if this behavior is due to the nature of the application (Console application). My end goal is to use The `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` class in a Class Library that will be consumed in an ASP.Net MVC application. The goal is to return data from a MemoryCache that gets populated everytime an XML file (data source) changes on a network folder.

So to do my implementation, I wrote a simple console app with a `List<>` of objects that will be cached. Here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using CachePersons.Core.Logging;

namespace CachePersons
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetPersons();
            GetPersons();
            GetPersons();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static List<string> GetPersons()
        {
            List<string> persons;

            Log.Debug("Entered GetPersons()");
            Console.WriteLine("Entered GetPersons()");

            //get default cache
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

            //get persons
            persons = (List<string>)cache.Get("Persons");

            //if cache does not contain the persons, create new list and add it to cache
            if (persons == null)
            {
                persons = GetPersonsFromDatabase();

                cache.Add("Persons", persons, new CacheItemPolicy());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Debug("    Found Data in Cache!");
                Console.WriteLine("    Found Data in Cache!");
            }

            Log.Debug("Exited GetPersons()");
            return persons;
        }

        static List<string> GetPersonsFromDatabase()
        {
            Log.Debug("    Populating Cache 1st time.");
            Console.WriteLine("    Populating Cache 1st time.");
            return new List<string>()
            {
                "John Doe",
                "Jane Doe"
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Then I built the project and opened 2 separate command windows, and ran then 1 after another. What I expect(ed) to see on the DebugView, Console Output, is that there will be only 1 time that the Cache will be populated, and that the 2nd .exe call will find the data in the cache, and return it from there. But that's not what's happening. See below screenshots from console and debugview.

[image]

and in DebugView...

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this behavior because I'm using a console app? How do I get the cache working across method calls in a class library? Also what considerations do I need to be aware of, if the same library is used in a web app (ASP.Net MVC on IIS 7.5 ).

Thank you!

Comment: That s related to the scope of your cache.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: Considering it's an in-memory cache, this behavior seems entirely reasonable. In what memory would the cache store its data if not in the data of your current process? Your 2 console apps processes don't share a common memory pool for storing the cache.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Was thinking the same thing. So how does it work for a ASP.Net IIS hosted web app? If I reference the class library that has the caching code like above, will subsequent calls from a webpage to the method that has caching implemented like above have access to the same memorycache until the IIS AppPool or application is recycled?

Comment: @Shiva web pages run in a (relatively) constant application pool in an appdomain. Contrary to two command line tools. A static object is per appdomain.

Comment: @Shiva you can have a static object, that will live as long as app pool.

Comment: Thanks everyone. the MemoryCache is working fine after I referenced my Library from the Web App. As @DarthVader and Menno have indicated, the cache was repopulating because I was testing it incorrectly by running 2 console app which are both in separate app domains.  Appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

You may find *[Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* helpful.

*PS*: If you plan to run your app on IIS. Your original code should be ok.

Comment: no. he is trying to work with in memory cache, what u are suggesting has different use cases.

Comment: Correct. I'm trying to cache data in a small XML file on a network drive at the IIS application level, and also refresh the cache when the XML file changes in content.

Comment: Then MemoryCache should be sufficient. :-)

Doesn't it work out for you?

Comment: Thanks everyone. the MemoryCache is working fine after I referenced my Library from the Web App. As DarthVader and Menno have indicated, the cache was repopulating because I was testing it incorrectly by running 2 console app which are both in separate app domains.  Appreciate everyone's help.